# Interpolating a sequential brewer palette as a legend for ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a plot with several observations overlaid on a histogram. The observations are collected sequentially and I need to observe the order they were collected. It's straightforward to use a `scale_colour_brewer` . The problem is, the maximum length of the sequential brewer palettes is 9. I have examples with as many as 20 observations and I'm not sure how to use interpolated colors. Below is some code that demonstrates my desired output with fewer than 10 points.

```
# Setting this to be > 9 will cause a warning and not produce the desired result.
observations = 9
subset <-1:observations
res = data.frame(x_data = rnorm(5000),TestID=1:5000)
ggplot(res,aes(x=x_data)) + 
  stat_bin(aes(y=..density..))+
  stat_density(colour="blue", fill=NA)+
  geom_point(data = res[res$TestID %in% subset,], 
             aes(x = x_data, 
                 y = 0, 
                 colour = as.factor(res$TestID[res$TestID %in% subset])
             ),
             size = 5) +scale_colour_brewer("Fancy title", type="seq", palette='Reds')
```

I know that as the number of observations becomes large, this plot will become difficult to read. However, I believe that with as many as 20 colors, it should be possible to interpret the results in my application.

Comment: You will either need to use `scale_colour_gradient2` or roll your own color scale using `scale_colour_manual`. The brewer palettes won't do more than 9 categories (and rightly so).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Expanding on my comment, you'll need to use `colorRampPalette`:

```
library(RColorBrewer)
blues_fun <- colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(9,"Blues"))
> blues_fun(20)
 [1] "#F7FBFF" "#ECF4FB" "#E1EDF8" "#D7E6F4" "#CDE0F1" "#C1D9ED" "#B0D2E7" "#A0CAE1" "#8BBFDC" "#75B3D8" "#62A8D2" "#519CCB"
[13] "#4090C5" "#3282BD" "#2474B6" "#1966AD" "#0E59A2" "#084B94" "#083D7F" "#08306B"
```

and then build the scale via `scale_colour_manual`:

```
ggplot(res,aes(x=x_data)) + 
  stat_bin(aes(y=..density..))+
  stat_density(colour="blue", fill=NA)+
  geom_point(data = res[res$TestID %in% subset,], 
             aes(x = x_data, 
                 y = 0, 
                 colour = as.factor(res$TestID[res$TestID %in% subset])
             ),
             size = 5) + 
  scale_colour_manual("Fancy title",values = blues_fun(9))
```

You simply have to hand off the resulting colors to the `values` argument.

Comment: Thanks, but can you elaborate on how to use scale_colour_manual? I got as far as colorRampPalette, but was not clear on the use of scale_colour_manual.

Comment: I just added blog post on exactly this: [How to expand color palette with ggplot and RColorBrewer](http://novyden.blogspot.com/2013/09/how-to-expand-color-palette-with-ggplot.html)